# What is a Self-cancelling Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Self-cancelling Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Self-cancelling Words™ | Not Self-cancelling Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WARM | HOT |
| CUSTOMIZE | PERSONALIZE |
| STOPPED | BLOCKED |
| PICTURE | IMAGE |
| FRIGHTENING | SCARY |
| ARRANGEMENT | LAYOUT |
| HIGHWAY | FREEWAY |
| PHOTOGRAPHER | PAPARAZZI |
| NUMEROUS | MANY |
| FAILING | DECLINING |
| BOXING | BATTLING |
| OVER | ACCOMPLISHED |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Self-cancelling Words™, Not Self-cancelling Words™
WARM, HOT
CUSTOMIZE, PERSONALIZE
STOPPED, BLOCKED
PICTURE, IMAGE
FRIGHTENING, SCARY
ARRANGEMENT, LAYOUT
HIGHWAY, FREEWAY
PHOTOGRAPHER, PAPARAZZI
NUMEROUS, MANY
FAILING, DECLINING 
BOXING, BATTLING
OVER, ACCOMPLISHED
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Self-cancelling Word™ or not on its own.

---

Hint :

> Self-cancelling Words™ are found using a **cursive** font.

Comment: No incoming hints?

Comment: @Techidiot Is that a request :-)?

Comment: Haha. Yess. Offcourse if you don't mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A self-cancelling word...

> When written in lower-case has the same number of tall letters (letters like $bdth$ that are taller than the letter $a$ for example) as letters that dip below the writing line (letters like $pq$).
>  It could be said that these two types 'cancel' each other out.

N.B.

> This only works with a cursive font, where the $\mathfrak{z}$ dips below the writing line and the $f$ is both tall and dips below the writing line (effectively 'cancelling' itself out).
>  Also, $i$ is not counted tall despite the dot!

For example...

> $\mathcal{warm}$ is self-cancelling as it has no tall or dipping letters.
>  $\mathcal{photographer}$ is self-cancelling as it has three tall letters ($hth$) that cancel three dipping letters ($pgp$).
>  $\mathcal{personali}\mathfrak{z}\mathcal{e}$ is not self-cancelling as it has an uneven two dipping letters ($p\mathfrak{z}$) to one tall letter ($l$).
>  $\mathcal{accomplished}$ is not self-cancelling as it has only one dipping letter ($p$) to three tall letters ($lhd$).

Update

> The correct term for portions of letters that are tall or dipping are [ascenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)) and [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) (thanks to @IAmInPLS for the links).

Comment: About the 'i' : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)

Comment: @IAmInPLS thanks for the edit! Great Puzzle!

Comment: @GPR did the cursive font, it looks really good :-). Thank you for solving it, good job!